# getting previous and next photos to show up in bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Image of my carousel:

[image: Carousel Image]

Hey guys, I'm trying to get my previous/next photos in my carousel to be edge (so you can see three photos, but only half of the first and third photo) to edge with a `10px` gap in between. Can't find a way to do this. I've gotten as far as setting the height of the carousel and centering the image. Now if I could just get the other images to slide up next to the displayed image!

Thank you guys!

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
    interval: 10000
  })
  $('.carousel .item').each(function() {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    if (next.next().length > 0) {
      next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    } else {
      $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
});     
</script>
```

```css
.carousel-inner {
  height: 515px;
}

.item {
  height: 515px;
}

.carousel-inner .item img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 515px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner {
  width: 150%;
  left: -25%;
}

.carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}

.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="assets/img/carousel-1.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/img/carousel-2.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/img/carousel-3.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">

      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```